I heard that Ubuntu 22.04 is capable of having ROS1 and ROS2 installed together but I'm not sure which versions I should get
After some research my results are ROS1 Noetic and ROS2 Humble. Will it be OK for these two versions to be together? I wanted to have ROS1 and ROS2 together on one laptop to start studying both of them.

ROS work also with Dockers. If you know about it you should have a look on
https://hub.docker.com/r/osrf/ros/

thanks I was trying ros1_bridge at the moment wasn't going so well I will try Dockers instead
